# How to invoke code after an event is completed in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple question.  I want to run a piece of code when an Event completes.  How do I do that in JQuery

Example

```
    $('#optNo').change(function(){
        if ($('input[id="optNo"]:checked').val() == 'No'){
         //do stuff
        }
     });

     function QuickCal(){
     //do some simple page specific logic
     }
```

I want to run QuickCal() when the change is completed.  I have seen this technique used on Ajax functionality.  ie( AjaxCall(stuff).done(stuffaftercall))

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous; change events are not. Perhaps you want to use the `blur` event instead?

Comment: What if the event is fired twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not making an asynchronous call you can simply use `mouseup` event:

```
$("#optNo").mouseup(function() {
     QuickCal();
});
```

or just:

```
$("#optNo").mouseup(QuickCal);
```